# Suppose that $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ and that for each $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that for a..

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, proof-verification

Suppose that $f$ is increasing on $[a,b]$ and that for each $\epsilon>0$, $\exists \delta>0$ such that for a measurable subset $E$ of $[a,b]$, if $|E| < \delta$ then $|f(E)|< \epsilon$. Show that $f$ is absolutely continuous on $[a,b]$

---

$\\$
Let $\epsilon>0$. Then choose $\delta>0$ such that if $E \subset [a,b]$ where $E$ is measurable and $|E| < \delta$ then $|f(E)| < \epsilon$.
Suppose $\{(c_k,d_k)\}^n$ is a collection of disjoint intervals in $[a,b]$ such that $\Sigma^n [d_k - c_k] < \delta$.

Then $|\bigcup^n (c_k,d_k)| = \Sigma^n |(c_k,d_k)| = \Sigma^n [d_k - c_k] < \delta $

Thus, by hypothesis, $|f(\bigcup^n (c_k,d_k))| < \epsilon$

Also,

$|f(\bigcup^n (c_k,d_k))|= |\bigcup^n f( (c_k,d_k)) = \Sigma^n |f(d_k) - f(c_k)|$

Where the last equality holds because $f$ is increasing. 
Thus:

$\Sigma^n |f(d_k) - f(c_k)|<\epsilon$ and so $f$ is absolutely continuous

---

I'm not sure if the part about equality holding because $f$ is increasing is true. If not, how do I use that $f$ is increasing to get that the measure is additive rather than subadditive?

Comment: Is the middle term in the line after "Also" supposed to be the *sum* of $|f((c_k, d_k))|$?

Comment: Nah, just meant to move the $\bigcup$ outside of the function I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a step:

$$
\left|f\left(\bigcup_{k=1}^n [c_k,d_k]\right) \right|
= \left|\bigcup_{k=1}^n f([c_k, d_k]) \right|
= \sum_{k=1}^n \left| f([c_k,d_k]) \right|
= \sum_{k=1}^n (f(d_k) - f(c_k))
$$

The first equality is just set theory. The second equality holds since $f$ is increasing, and thus any two of the sets $f([c_k, d_k])$ are disjoint or intersect in a single point. The third equality holds since $f([c_k, d_k]) = [f(c_k), f(d_k)]$, again because $f$ is increasing.

I've also changed the open intervals $(c_k, d_k)$ to closed intervals $[c_k, d_k]$ since there is a small but annoying issue with open intervals; if $f$ is not strictly increasing, then $f((c_k, d_k))$ might or might not include the endpoints $f(c_k)$ and $f(d_k)$.

Comment: I was wondering about the third equality. Note that in my class, increasing just means non-decreasing, rather than strictly increasing. It's still gaurenteed that these sets are disjoint???

Comment: They might not be disjoint, but their intersection can only be a point. I've edited my answer to address this.